# how can i use react-chartjs-2 without npm package manager

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I can't use npm to manage the library, so i am exploring the possibility of using it directly in the browser.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Is there any docs where it specifies how this is possible and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it via `CDN`, like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs-2/2.1.0/react-chartjs-2.min.js">
```

Comment: i think i am not clear in my question :). I know that you can import this in a script. but how can i use it without a package manager.

basically i can't do 
import {<Component>} from 'react-chartjs'

Reason being i have a hybrid app where i am already using ngReact that is importing full reactjs library. If i use the above statement the library imports full reactjs library and then the react-chartjs library that ends up being a file of more than 30k lines where reactjs library is duplicated

Comment: I see. In my opinion, I don't think of other ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent reloading of reactjs library through this npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-global-shim

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the file the CDN provides

```
factory((global.ReactChartjs2 = {}),global.React,global.Chart
```

To get **Bar**, add this line to the top:

```
var Bar = window['ReactChartjs2'].Bar;
```